# Does ''recommended for publication subject to minor revision'' implies aceptance?

Tags: publications, phd, research-process, peer-review

I have submitted my manuscript to one of the peer-reviewed journals of chemistry and the decision was 'recommended for publication subject to minor revision'. I have submitted the revision but two weeks have passed and the status is still showing that the manuscript is in peer review in scholar one. Please suggest future steps.
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does "minor revision" mean "accepted with minor revision"?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/58133/does-minor-revision-mean-accepted-with-minor-revision)

Comment: The paper isn't accepted until it is accepted. The 'minor revision' must be done to the satisfaction of the editor before it is would be considered for acceptance.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on who made the "recommendation". If it was a reviewer, then, no, it doesn't imply acceptance. It makes it more likely, but not assured.

An editor can, and sometimes does, reject a paper even with positive recommendations. That might be for business or space reasons, perhaps.

I think the "future steps" is to wait for a final decision from the editor. Or, ask the editor if there is anything more to do.

Comment: The comments were made by the editor.

Comment: A good sign then.

Answer (score 1):

It is highly likely that your paper will be accepted. It is usually the editor who makes such decisions (if this decision has been mentioned in the email they sent you, then it was the editor). If the email also mentions that, upon submission, your paper will not be sent out for review, then you may want to contact the editor (although if I were you, I would wait a bit more). But, if it does not mention such a thing, I suggest you wait a couple of more weeks as two weeks is clearly not enough for the review process to move forward.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. In the email it was not mentioned whether it will be sent out for review or not. Should I send a reminder mail to the editorial office in that case?

Comment: In that case, maybe it is not the policy of the journal to state clearly whether the submission will be sent out for review or not. However, If the required changes were very minimal (e.g., choice of language, punctuation), it is likely that the editor will make the final decision. But, if the required changes were somewhere between minor and major revision, then your paper could be with the reviewers. In the first case, you could email the editorial team but personally I think two weeks is a bit soon. In the second case though emailing the editor is not a good idea.

Comment: I guess you are worried about the fate of your paper but as I mentioned above the decision you have received is very positive. So, I think you could relax and maybe wait a bit more. Perhaps, wait a couple of weeks if you believe the paper is with the editor before sending an email. Of course, this is just a suggestion and you are the person who will make the final decision.